# How to solve equations of the form $ax^4+bx^2+c$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> **Question:**  Find the values of $x$ for the following equation $$108x^4-507x^2+300$$

**My attempt:**

I have the solution and it says to use the quadratic formula. However how would I apply that here?

Thank you

Comment: Hint:  let $z=x^2$.

Comment: I have tried that but then I get a $\frac{300}{z^2}$

Comment: Not following.  the equation becomes $108z^2-507z+300=0$.  A perfectly good quadratic equation in $z$.

Comment: No problem at all.

Comment: Do not forget to accept an answer if it's what fits you to your question so that the threat of your question becomes green (answered).

Comment: @THISISIT453 This is a **biquadratic equation** and it is in general $a_4x^4+a_2x^2+a_0=0$, where $a_4\neq 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $y=x^2 $. Then $y^2 = x^4$. Your equation becomes : $108y^2 - 507y + 300 = 0$. Solve that and then replace $x = y^2$ for the solutions you found and you will find the solutions to your starting one.